# How to architect a simple SELECT form element in a react-redux-form application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm building a react-redux, redux-form application. I'm going to have one page where I want to render a SELECT box which pulls a list of options dynamically from the server. My question is how to architect this simple form in a react-redux app.

Should this SELECT form element be powered by react-redux-form? Should I use redux/reducers to query and store the state which will power the dropdown options? Or is that overkill?

Answer (score 1):

If your select box is a part of a large form, that is submitted, maybe even validated, and sent to the server, use `redux-form`.

If your select box is just a means for selecting a single value for the purposes of for example filtering a list, `redux-form` is overkill and you will be better off without. Use component state to keep tabs on which option is selected, but store the options fetched from the server inside the redux store.

Comment: The select box will have it's options obtained from the server and then sent to the server. So redux-form sounds like the way to go...

Comment: Do you know of an examples/tutorials that show how to populate a redux-form select box with values from an AJAX call and then submit back to the server? Thanks